# Canopy installation problems, a solution for TIF?

Tags: installation, pip, tiff, easy-install, libtiff

I've been starting with Python in Canopy Enthought for a little more than a month now. I'm struggling with installation at so many levels it drives me crazy.
I want to install modules to deal with tif files, in order to create multiimage tof, etc.

tifffile 0.4
PyLibTiff

I cannot get them through easy_install.
I tried pip install tifffile

I keep getting these errors:
error: Visual Studio 2008 Express Edition was found in your path, but
Visual Studio 2008 is required to build extension modules on a
64-bit platform.

Visual studio is installed, I installed a 2013 express version, then downloaded and installed 2008 too, nothing seems to work.

This is driving my crazy, and honestly I'm not sure I handle the basics of how python handle the different modules. Through different .zip packages, I ended with the tifffile code, I don't know where to put it. There is a .exe installer for PyLibTiff but I can't get it to work either.

If anybody can help, that would save the life of my computer, I feel like it's gonna learn to fly soon.

Thanks a lot !!

Dam.

Comment: The error message says that you have installed Visual Studio Express 2008. Do you have that installed?

Comment: It is installed yes, do I need the "non express version"?

Answer (score 0):

You need Visual Studio 2008. Not Visual Studio Express 2008.